# Angularjs accurate dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a dropdown select with some options to filter the displayed list according to the selected option.

```
<form class="list">
  <label class="item item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Select career</span>
    <select ng-model="searchFromSelect">
        <option></option>
        <option>Admin</option>
        <option>IT</option>
        <option>Transport</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <ion-item ng-repeat="career in careers | filter:searchFromSelect" class="item-icon-right balanced" ng-click="openCareer(career)">{{ career.AREA }}
    <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
  </ion-item>

</form>
```

controller

```
$scope.vagas = response.data;

console.log : {"data":[{"ID":"1","AREA":"Admin","Benefits":"Transport"},{"ID":"2","AREA":"IT","Benefits":"Transport"}]}
```

How can I make it more accurate to show me the list items according only to "AREA"?

Note that if I choose Transport, it displays both "Admin" and "IT" because "Transport" is a benefit from them.

I was trying to use "strict" like [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the filter filter [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), you can specify your filter expression as an object. To filter only on AREA properties, use :

```
ng-repeat="career in `careers| filter:{AREA: searchFromSelect}"
```